# Post image to facebook wall (where to store image)

Tags: iphone, image, facebook

My app must publish screenshot to the facebook wall (as well as several other social networks). 
Where should I upload images that will be shown in the facebook feed?

Should I create photo album with my app images? 
Or it's better to use free image hosting like ImageShack? 

Maybe some other ways?

Which approach is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an **Amazon S3** bucket. I've used this before for an image hosting app, it's not free but not expensive either and you have a lot of control.

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

Very easy to set-up and you only pay for what you use.

---

Hosting the image on **facebook** may not be suitable for sharing to other social networks.

Depending on the number of uploads you may violate the terms of service for the free image hosting sites like **ImageShack**.